# Finding overlap between two matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, routes, overlap

We have two 4x4 matrices each have their own source and destination coordinates and we can only move horizontally first and then vertically to reach our destination (e.g. if you want to go from (0,0) to (2,3) you can go through the route (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,3),(2,3)). I don't have a problem with printing the routes but I want to see the overlapping between these two matrices. Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Here is the code of showing the route :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
int a[4] = { 0,1,2,3 };
int b[4] = { 0,1,2,3 }; 
int x, y, z, t; cout<<"Enter your source coordination : " ; 
cin>>x>>y; 
cout<<"Enter your destination coordination : " ; 
cin>>z>>t; 
if (x == z&&y == t)  
printf("(%d,%d)",x,y); 
else {
 if (x <= z&&y <= t) { 
for (; a[y] <= t; a[y]++) printf("(%d,%d)",x,a[y]);  
for (; b[x] < z; b[x]++) printf("(%d,%d)",b[x]+1,t); } 
 if (x <= z&&y >= t) {
for (; a[y] >= t; a[y]--) printf("(%d,%d)",x,a[y]); 
 for (; b[x] < z; b[x]++) printf("(%d,%d)",b[x]+1,t); } 
if (x > z&&y > t) { 
for (; a[y] >= t; a[y]--) printf("(%d,%d)",x,a[y]);
 for (; b[x] > z ; b[x]--) printf("(%d,%d)",b[x]-1,t); } 
if (x > z&&y < t) {
 for (; a[y] <= t; a[y]++) printf("(%d,%d)",x,a[y]);
 for (; b[x] > z; b[x]--) printf("(%d,%d)",b[x]-1,t);    
 }
   } 
_getch();

}
```

Comment: The matrices that you have used in your example are 4x1 not 4x4 as described in your question. Could you perhaps clarify if your matrices are of the form `int x[4]` or `int x[4][4]` ???

Answer (score 0):

If the question refers to matrices of the form `int a[4][4]`,
you can loop through them and compare their elements. Then, if they match - place them in another matrix, using the same indexes. If they don't match - you can simply place 0 as value for the respective element of the new matrix.